# What will happen if I keep incrementing an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, set, increment

I have a simple question: what will happen if I keep incrementing an iterator when it reaches the end() (one past the last) of a C++ STL container? e.g.

```
set<int> intSet;
intSet.insert(0);
intSet.insert(1);
intSet.insert(2);
set<int>::iterator setIter = intSet.begin();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  setIter++;
```

so, will setIter always be intSet.end()? or this is an undefined behavior (can give me inconsistent junk)?

Comment: @Tahlil Probably, (s)he afraids to damage the universe, because we can not know what will happen.

Comment: @Tahlil just because it might work does not mean it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Joe My question had the purpose of him telling us what research he had done before asking the question. Nothing else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mere act of incrementing it will do *nothing*, at least in the GNU compilers.

If you try to dereference it, that invokes undefined behavior.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810142/are-c-iterators-safe) for more discussion.

Comment: Thx, yes, I know I should not dereference it. I just need to know if this can give me consistent behavior. Seems like it won't if I use different compilers.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw a runtime error in VS2013. However, it will not in G++ (ideone). However it is undefined behavior if you ever use it. It is definitely not equal to `intSet.end()`